# How randomly set courses to students?

Tags: java, java-8

I have two lists of strings. One of them contains 200 strings - students name, id, and other one contains 10 courses names (math, it etc).

The question is: how to randomly assign students to courses?
One student can contain from 1 to 3 courses.

My code:

```
private List<String> generatedNames() {
  Faker names = new Faker();
  return IntStream.range(0, 200).mapToObj(i -> names.name().firstName())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private List<Integer> studentID() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return IntStream.range(0, 200).mapToObj(i -> random.nextInt(99999))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

    public List<StudentConstructor> student() {
    List<String> name = generatedNames();
    List<Integer> id = studentID();
    List<String> course = setCourse();
    return IntStream.range(0, name.size()).mapToObj(i -> new StudentConstructor(name.get(i), id.get(i), course.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And that's how I try to set courses:

```
private List<String> setCourse(List<String> course) {
    List<String> names = generatedNames();
    int nTimes = names.size() / course.size();
    return course.stream().map(course -> Collections.nCopies(nTimes, course))
            .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

but each course sets only once to each student, how set from 1 to 3 for each student ??

for example:

> name1 course1, course2, course3

> name2 course2

> name3 course1, course3

Comment: I read your question several times but still cannot understand what you have and you want. please rephrase your sentences and express your requirements clearly.

Comment: You would also have to clarify requirements more precisely. I guess: all students should be have at least one class, and a max of 3, all random? ... besides, one easy solution: simply iterate your student list. For each student: **shuffle** the list of classes (meaning: bring them into random order). Then create  a random number C between 1 and 3. And just assign the first C classes to that student. And so on. That gives you random number of classes, and random classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems that the existing data model for `Student` has to be modified because each student should be assigned to several courses:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Student {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private List<String> courses; // instead of single String course
}
```

Second, it is better to use [`Random::ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) method to generate N random numbers in the required range.

For example, assuming that there's a String array of user names, random names and IDs can be generated like this:

```java
static Random random = new SecureRandom();

static List<String> buildNames() {
    return random.ints(200, 0, names.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> names[i])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

static List<Integer> buildIds() {
    return random.ints(200, 10_000, 100_000) // generate 5-digit unique random IDs
            .distinct()
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Similarly, the list of courses *per student* can be generated providing a random number of courses (assuming there's a String array `courses`):

```java
static List<List<String>> buildCourses() {
    return IntStream
            .range(0, 200)
            .mapToObj(
                    a -> random
                            .ints(1 + random.nextInt(3), 0, courses.length)
                            .mapToObj(i -> courses[i])
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then, instances of `Student` can be created like this:

```java
List<String> names = buildNames();
List<Integer> ids = buildIds();
List<List<String>> courses = buildCourses();

IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Student(names.get(i), ids.get(i), courses.get(i)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Example output:

```
tudent(name=Joan, id=26161, courses=[Ecology, Philosophy, French])
Student(name=Abe, id=56138, courses=[Chemistry, Architecture])
Student(name=Jim, id=87055, courses=[English, History])
Student(name=Jake, id=18101, courses=[Philosophy, History])
Student(name=Brian, id=38094, courses=[English, Web Design, Geometry])
Student(name=Jake, id=58020, courses=[Computer Science])
Student(name=Audrey, id=86903, courses=[German, Web Design, Ecology])
Student(name=Adele, id=97649, courses=[Philosophy, French, German])
Student(name=Jake, id=90515, courses=[German, French])
Student(name=Jane, id=19288, courses=[Computer Science])
```